# what exactly is VGA

Tags: vga, graphics, computer-architecture

is VGA (Video Graphics Array) a piece of video hardware, or is it a video output standard, whatever that means, or is it just an interface between the graphics card and the display device. these are all the answers I got when searching for the definition of VGA

Comment: Strictly speaking it's the standard but it has been popularized also as the name of the connector, that's all.

Comment: What Changan said. We call it a "VGA connector" but it is more correctly a [DE-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature) connector that happens to carry signals that adhere to the VGA standard. The first paragraph of the Wikipedia [Video Graphics Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array) page sums it up pretty well, where it says that technically it is an IBM adaptor and protocol but has been adapted as a colloquial term for the entire chain of connector, cable, display resolution and other parts.

Comment: the Wikipedia page also stated that it is a video display controller.

Comment: @DjebbarAbderrahmene - The entire Wikipedia article on Video Graphics Array (VGA) has issues and lacks verified cited factual statements. I would not use that particular Wikipedia article for knowlege building.

Answer (score 5):

It's not exactly a *specific* piece of hardware; it's multiple "standards" that were introduced by the IBM "PS/2 Display Adapter" graphics card – it could mean any of these depending on context:

1. the [programming interface](https://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Hardware) (API, memory layout) that the OS could use to program the graphics card, i.e. to provide the image output, switch graphics modes, etc.;
2. the physical and electrical interface to connect a display to the card (the "VGA" port and the specific signal format that goes over it);
3. the 640x480 "VGA" screen resolution that these cards were capable of;
4. any graphics card that is primarily compatible with the above (e.g. the "[PS/2 Display Adapter](https://www.vgamuseum.info/index.php/cpu/item/1014-ibm-ps2-display-adapter)" was a VGA graphics card).

Comment: The actual technical term for point 2 Is a D-SUB connector. It was this connector that would allow a signal using the VGA graphics mode on a VGA card. CGA could also be used over composit however, and there was also a TANDY graphics mode that used a serial connector. As these graphics modes were common at the same time, the D-SUB connector was often also called the VGA connector, because it was the only one capable of displaying VGA, a video mode that everyone wanted anyway.

Comment: No, I did specifically mean "VGA" there – there's a lot of uses for D-Sub connectors, including RS232 serial and multiple video output standards (the earlier IBM CGA used a DE-9 connector, like serial ports, and that's also a D-Sub connector), but only one specific arrangement is referred to as "VGA connector". (It's like how Ethernet ports are called "Ethernet ports" when there's a need to distinguish them by wiring, as "RJ45 port" can mean multiple things even on the same device...)

Comment: Right. I actually did not know that d-sub or sub-d as some sites call it, is a collection name for this v shape connector with pins. I thought their collection name was serial cable. That said, some sites say a VGA cable is not a d-sub DE15 cable, but a DVI-D cable, which I disagree about.